# Retrieving nodes from index with transaction in neo4jrestclient

Tags: python, transactions, neo4j

I'd like to do a batch operation on a bunch of nodes that are already saved to neo4j, ultimately to create relations between them. I have something like

```
with gdb.transaction():
    for s_id, d_id in nodelist:
        sn = nidx['nid'][s_id].single
        dn = nidx['nid'][d_id].single
```

where `nidx` is an index that I've made (and 'nid', s_id are the key/value pair). However, it looks like `nidx['nid'][s_id]` is a TransactionOperationProxy object, though I was intending for it to be a node. Is there any way I can convert it to a node, or at least use it to create a relation between `sn` and `dn` (something like sn.Follows(dn))?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like a bug. Let me see it.

Comment: I have added a [new test](https://github.com/versae/neo4j-rest-client/blob/master/neo4jrestclient/tests.py#L1185) for debugging this, but I think that is not supported by the Neo4 REST API. The explanation is you are requesting the first nodes of an index and, before doing anything with them, you need to finish the transaction for getting the URLs of the nodes in order to create a relationship between both using the REST API.

Comment: Why are you using an index to look up by ID rather than just getting by ID directly?

Comment: @espeed `s_id` and `d_id` aren't the 'real' neo4j id's, I'm reading them from another list. If there's a way to save nodes into the database with a given ID that would make it easier, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the batch loader, but it would be easier to do with a Gremlin script.

If your `nodelist` is a list of node-ID pairs, here's the Gremlin script to batch load the edges (untested)...

```
// gremlin.groovy

def batch_load(nodelist, label) {
  g.setMaxBufferSize(0)
  g.startTransaction()
  try {
    for (entry in nodelist) {
      s_id = entry[0]
      d_id = entry[1]
      // if s_id and d_id are actual node IDs, you don't need to use an index...
      sn = g.idx('someindex').get('nid',s_id)[0]
      dn = g.idx('someindex').get('nid',d_id)[0]
      g.addEdge(sn,dn,label)
    }
    g.stopTransaction(TransactionalGraph.Conclusion.SUCCESS)
    return true
  } catch (e) {
    g.stopTransaction(TransactionalGraph.Conclusion.FAILURE)  
    return e
  }
}
```

And here's how you would execute it in Bulbs -- you'll need to modify this for neo4jrestclient...

```
>>> from bulbs.neoj4server import Graph
>>> g = Graph()
>>> g.scripts.update('/path/to/gremlin.groovy')
>>> script = g.scripts.get('batch_load')
>>> params = dict(nodelist=your_node_list, label="follows")
>>> g.gremlin.execute(script, params)
```